# Why is CreateFileA succeeding in Windows XP and failing in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, reverse-engineering, kernel32

I'm working through a reverse engineering exercise using olly.

```
00402D71  |. 6A 00          PUSH 0                                   ; /hTemplateFile = NULL
00402D73  |. 68 80000000    PUSH 80                                  ; |Attributes = NORMAL
00402D78  |. 6A 03          PUSH 3                                   ; |Mode = OPEN_EXISTING
00402D7A  |. 6A 00          PUSH 0                                   ; |pSecurity = NULL
00402D7C  |. 6A 00          PUSH 0                                   ; |ShareMode = 0
00402D7E  |. 68 00000080    PUSH 80000000                            ; |Access = GENERIC_READ
00402D83  |. FF75 F0        PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-10]               ; |C:\Windows\system32\eLearnRE#5.dat
00402D86  |. E8 DF642300    CALL <JMP.&KERNEL32.CreateFileA>         ; \CreateFileA
```

On Windows 10, I created the eLearnRE#5.dat file and verified that NTFS permissions make it readable.   But even like that I get 0xFFFFFFFF with ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (00000002) as a result of the CALL CreateFileA.

This is what I tried already (without success)

- Copy and pasted the name from ollydbg to make sure I don't have any typos
- Compared the two filenames letter by letter in notepad to check for typos
- Patched the process memory to try reading an existing file in C:\temp\test.txt (just in case c:\windows\System32\eLearnRE#5.dat had some special restrictions because it's in a system folder)
- Put some data into the file just in case it had trouble handling a blank file for some reason.
- Ran olly as Administrator

This works perfectly fine in Windows XP, but not in Windows 10.  Why?

Comment: what is NtCreateFile return ? look here at first and check name here

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm not trying to figure out how to write this code - I'm convinced the code is 100% ok.   I'm trying to figure out why it doesn't work for me in particular.   This executable is from a reverse engineering course and the video lecture shows successful return code as long as the file is present.    The more I think about it, maybe there is some difference between XP and Windows 10 in the way it executes.

Comment: Turns out my hunch was correct.  On Windows XP it succeeds with no problem.   I tried on two Windows 10 machines and the same code fails.   I looked at the documentation for CreateFileA and it doesn't say anything about deprecated.   Why is it failing on Windows 10?   I edited the question title accordingly

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The credit for the answer goes to Hans Passant for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector

- On 64bit windows, 32bit applications are redirected to C:\windows\syswow64
- As soon as I moved the file to C:\windows\syswos64, things started to work as expected